# Why this keeps appering - Uncaught TypeError: slides is not a function at setActive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have just started to learn programming and have been trying to do as much research and training as possible. However, I came across something that I cannot resolve. When copying a web page from a You Tube video, an error appears that prevents me from having the slider working correctly.
As I have no basis to understand the error and no matter how many turns I can't unravel it.
I put the code to see if someone can explain to me what is happening.
No error appears in the text editor, the error appears when I inspect the code in the search engine. Basically the slider doesn't work and when inspecting the code in the search engine the following appears:
(index):66 Uncaught TypeError: slides is not a function
at setActive ((index):66:17)
at HTMLSpanElement. ((index):74:21)

Thank you all for your time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1.0">
        <title>Suzuki Bike Website Landing Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="main">
            <header>
                <a href="#"><img src="logo.png" class="logo"></a>
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li><a href="#">Top Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </header>
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Ready To <span>Race</span></h2>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Ride Now</a>
                <img src="DL1050RC_M2_BT1_Right_2400x1500.png" class="bike">
            </div>

            <!--Slider Content-->
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slides active">
                    <h2><span>Engine</span><br>1037 cc</h2>
                    <h2><span>Power</span><br>107.3 HP</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="slides">
                    <h2><span>Fuel Tank</span><br>20L</h2>
                    <h2><span>Transmition</span><br>6 speed</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="slides">
                    <h2><span>Weight</span><br>247 Kg</h2>
                    <h2><span>SIRS</span><br>ABS</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <ul class="sci">
                    <li><a href="#"><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="dots">
                    <span class="dot active"></span>
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script> 
    
    
        <script>
            const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides');
            const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');

            function setActive(i){
                for(slide of slides)
                slide.classList.remove('active');
                slides(i).classList.add('active');
                for(dot of dots)
                dot.classList.remove('active');
                dots(i).classList.add('active');
            }

            for(let j =0; j<dots.length; j++){
                dots[j].addEventListener('click', function(){
                    setActive(j)
                })
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap'); 
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
:root
{
    --black: #2f2f2f;
    --white: #fff;
    --red: #f83038;
}
.main
{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #323232);
    padding: 30px 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.main::before
{
    content: "Adventure";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 16vw;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
header
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vh;
    padding: 30px 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo
{
    max-width: 80px;
}
.navigation
{
    display: flex;
}
.navigation li
{
    list-style: none;
}
.navigation li a
{
    position: relative;
    color: var(--white);
    margin-left: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.25s;
}
.navigation li a:hover
{
    color: var(--red);
}
.content
{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.content h2
{
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: var(--white);
    text-align: center;
}
.content h2 span
{
    font-weight: 700;
}
.btn
{
    display: inline-block;
    background: var(--red);
    color: var(--white);
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 16px 36px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    transition: 0.25s;
}
.btn:hover
{
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}
.bike
{
  max-width: 80%;
}
.footer
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.sci
{
    display: flex;
}
.sci li
{
    list-style: none;
}
.sci li a
{
    color: var(--white);
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-right: 20px;
    transition: 0.25s;
}
.sci li a:hover
{
    color: var(--red);
}
.dots
{
    display: flex;
}
.dots .dot
{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.dots .dot.active
{
    background: var(--white);
}
.slider .slides
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 100px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slider .slides.active
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slider .slides h2
{
    color: var(--white);
    font-size: 3em;
}
.slider .slides h2:last-child
{
    text-align: end;
}
.slider .slides h2 span
{
    color: var(--red);
    font-size: 0.5em;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: You need to include the error. Please update your question with it.

Comment: Thanks for the alert. I already changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

`slides(i).classList.add('active');`

`slides` is not a function, but you are calling it.

Try this instead:

`slides.classList.add('active');`